# In Python, what is the purpose of __length_hint__ of the set_iterator class?

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3.10 (and probably earlier), if you use the `iter` function on a set you get an object of type `<class 'set_iterator'>`, and that class includes the method `__length_hint__`.
I understand that the idea of `__length_hint__` is to provide an estimate for the length of an object. But sets already support the `len()` function.
So why implement `__length_hint__` on the iterator? Does it serve a purpose that I'm missing?

Comment: Well what if you want the length or an estimate, but I don't give you a set but just a set iterator? Possibly even already partially consumed?

Comment: Relevant reading: [PEP 424 "A method for exposing a length hint"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/) and the entry for [`object.__length_hint__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__length_hint__) in the Python Data Model docs.

Comment: So the value returned by `__length_hint__` changes as the iterator is consumed. That's something I didn't realize.

Comment: The real difference between `__len__` and `__length_hint__` the former is a method of the container object while the latter is a method of the iterator. If you have only the iterator, `__length_hint__` is your only option.